# Applying a page layout to a page using SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout

Is there a way to apply a page layout to a specific page using SharePoint Designer 2010? I know how to change the page layout used using the browser GUI and I know how to create/modify a page layout in Designer. My question is whether a page layout can be assigned from within SharePoint Designer 2010.